# What am I doing wrong here (issue with loops)

Tags: linux, shell-script

This thing here

```
n=0
x=1
while [ $n -lt 6 ]
do
         n=$(( n+1 ))
         echo "sasadgsad gsda $n" >> /home/test/rptest

if [ $n -eq 5 ]
   then
      while [ $x -le 5 ]
      do
         echo "end of line$x" >> /home/test/rptest
         x=$(( x+1 ))
      done
 fi
done
```

Output this thing

```
sasadgsad gsda 1
sasadgsad gsda 2
sasadgsad gsda 3
sasadgsad gsda 4
sasadgsad gsda 5
end of line1
end of line2
end of line3
end of line4
end of line5
sasadgsad gsda 6
```

That 11th line shouldn't be there... Shouldn't the first while thing finish when n = 5? Why does it create that last line?

Thank you for the help :)

I even tried it with n=1 and while [ $n -le 5 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script with proper indentation:

```
n=0
x=1
while [ $n -lt 6 ]; do
    n=$(( n+1 ))
    echo "sasadgsad gsda $n" >> /home/test/rptest

    if [ $n -eq 5 ]; then
        while [ $x -le 5 ]; do
            echo "end of line$x" >> /home/test/rptest
            x=$(( x+1 ))
        done
    fi
done
```

Your outer loop runs from 0 to 5, which is six times.  Since you update `n` at the start of the outer loop, the value of `n` will go from 1 to 6 in the body of the loop.  When `n` is 5, you run another loop from 1 to 5 outputting `end of line...`.  When that's done, you still have one iteration of the outer loop to do.

Another way to write the script in `bash`:

```
for (( n=1; n<=5; ++n )); do
    printf 'sasadgsad gsda %s\n' "$n"

    if (( n == 5 )); then
        for (( x=1; x<=5; ++x )); do
            printf 'end of line%s\n' "$x"
        done
    fi
done >>/home/test/rptest
```

This would *not* have the same issue because the outer loop stops when `n` reaches 6.

However, if you just want to append the output of the inner loop after the that of the outer, you might just as well run the after each other:

```
for (( n=1; n<=5; ++n )); do
    printf 'sasadgsad gsda %s\n' "$n"
done >>/home/test/rptest

for (( n=1; n<=5; ++x )); do
    printf 'end of line%s\n' "$n"
done >>/home/test/rptest
```

or, for this simple example only,

```
printf 'sasadgsad gsda %s\n' {1..5} >>/home/test/rptest
printf 'end of line%s\n' {1..5} >>/home/test/rptest
```

Comment: Thanks! The "for" version of this is much better, I'm gonna use it from now on :D

Comment: @iamAguest Just remember that `sh` may not understand this type of loop, so run your scripts with `bash` to be sure it works, not `sh`.